# Proving that operator is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have an operator $A : L_{p}[0,1] \to L_{p}[0,1]$ which is $Ax(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds$ (namely Hardy operator) I want to show that this operator isn’t compact for $1 \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$ so for the case when $p=\infty$ I think this problem can be solved with constructing and example of sequence of functions for which from the image of this sequence we can’t deduce a fundamental sequence , but I can’t construct it. Also I want some hint for proving non-compactness for other cases

Comment: A similar question has been asked before, it should help you work out some details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919027/t-l20-1-to-l20-1-tfx-frac1x-int-0x-fy-is-a-bounded-bu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, but still these method doesn’t work for $p=\infty$

Comment: the construction in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/256953/152424) works for $p=\infty$.